# How to obtain current user environment in pam_script?

Tags: pam, kerberos

I'm running `pam_script` after `pam_krb5` with a session open script.

In my script, I need to use the ticket cache generated by krb5 to do something. Well, the script was actually run as root, and `KRB5CCNAME` or `PAM_KRB5CCNAME` is all empty.

What should I do?